# What is the order of execution in ASP.NET MVC Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, action-filter

Say I have a controller called "HomeController" which inherits from Mvc.Controller. Also say I have written the constructor of the controller and some filters for some actions.

```
Public Class ClientController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    Public Sub New()
        ''Some code
    End Sub

    <SomeActionFilter()> _
    Function Index() As ActionResult
        Return View()
    End Function
End Class
```

My questions are :

1. What is the order of execution of constructor, filter, action?
2. Can I have a filter for the Constructor, if I do not want to run the code in it by checking for some conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructor will go first.  Depending on the type of filter that either the filter or action method will execute second.  See here for the [filter types](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-14-cs.aspx).

Filter doesn't intercept constructor.  If you want to control the constructor invocation of Controller, you need to build a custom controller factory by implementing `IControllerFactory` (or `DefaultControllerFactory`) and register it with `ControllerBuidler`, e.g.:
`ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(typeof(MyControllerFactory))` on application start.

> if I do not want to run the code in it
>   by checking for some conditions?

Can't you write that code directly in the constructor (e.g. the check condition in the base controller to reuse)?  Why do you need a filter in this case?